# Codestar framework allow theme options to show when the WordPress role is a different one than admin

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, wordpress-theming

Currently in my setup theme options shows only when the WordPress admin role user signs in into the dashboard. The codestar theme options does not show up when a user with another role such as author or editor sings in into the WordPress dashboard. I want to be able to allow user other than admin to configure settings through codestar theme options.

I want to know if this is possible and how to achieve this.